# Fast indexing of symmetrical matrix

Tags: fortran

In a large code written in Fortran08 for calculating thermodynamic equilibria and phase diagrams I use many symmetric matrices which I store as 1D arrays and index using a small function

```
integer function ixsym(i,j)
   if(i.gt.j) then
      ixsym=j+i*(i-1)/2
   else
      ixsym=i+j*(j-1)/2
   endif
   return
end
```

This works perfectly but after improving the speed of various other parts of the code this routine now takes 15-20% of the calculation time (it is used very often).  I assume there are various ways of speeding this up but I do not know C or other way to replace this function so I am looking for help.  I use gfortran but the replacement has to be portable.

Bo Sundman

Comment: Don't use a function unless you are sure it will be inlined by the compiler, and do the full computation (j+i*(i-1)/2) only when it's really necessary (try not to do it in inner loops): usually you would order the computation so that the inner loop works on contiguous data, so you can simply increment the index instead of computing it from scratch. You may have a look at BLAS/LAPACK source for packed symmetric functions to see how it's done (the `dsp*` functions).

Comment: Why not just store them as 2D arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Fortran compilers used to have optimization on par or better than C compilers.
So I would not expect a gain just by switching language and rather focus on algorithmic improvements.

- How about replacing the calculation of the index tranformation by a lookup table?
  Do you have the memory to store the `ixsym` values for given `i` and `j` indices?
  Yes it counters your memory for cpu trade-off, but if you have many matrices this extra one might help.
- Is it really necessary to calculate the transformation at all times? E.g. if you iterate over elements: `ixsym(i, j+1) = ixsym(i, j) + 1`, if  `i < j`.
- Another idea, though hardware specific, might be to order your data differently, so that it stays within cache areas of the CPU. ([Link](https://www.particleincell.com/2012/memory-code-optimization/))

**About your index transformation:**

I initially thought you used some variation of the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) to enumerate your symmetric 2D array. I asked my friend Ruby to plot a few pairs and she told me:

```
(0, 0) ->  0  (0, 1) ->  0  (0, 2) ->  1  (0, 3) ->  3  (0, 4) ->  6
(1, 0) ->  0  (1, 1) ->  1  (1, 2) ->  2  (1, 3) ->  4  (1, 4) ->  7
(2, 0) ->  1  (2, 1) ->  2  (2, 2) ->  3  (2, 3) ->  5  (2, 4) ->  8
(3, 0) ->  3  (3, 1) ->  4  (3, 2) ->  5  (3, 3) ->  6  (3, 4) ->  9
(4, 0) ->  6  (4, 1) ->  7  (4, 2) ->  8  (4, 3) ->  9  (4, 4) -> 10
```

I would have expected only two occurences of a calculated index, but I see three for some pairs. Is this intended?

**Update:**

It was the index start, as fellow user Jean-Claude Arbaut pointed out in his comment.
Here is Ruby's answer with indices starting at 1:

```
(1, 1) ->  1  (1, 2) ->  2  (1, 3) ->  4  (1, 4) ->  7  (1, 5) -> 11
(2, 1) ->  2  (2, 2) ->  3  (2, 3) ->  5  (2, 4) ->  8  (2, 5) -> 12
(3, 1) ->  4  (3, 2) ->  5  (3, 3) ->  6  (3, 4) ->  9  (3, 5) -> 13
(4, 1) ->  7  (4, 2) ->  8  (4, 3) ->  9  (4, 4) -> 10  (4, 5) -> 14
(5, 1) -> 11  (5, 2) -> 12  (5, 3) -> 13  (5, 4) -> 14  (5, 5) -> 15
```

Comment: Your friend Ruby is wrong. I asked my friend Fortran and its array indices start at 1 ;-)

Comment: Ruby does only what I tell her. (Not like Siri). And I had a too quick look at [Dr. Google's answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=index+fortran+array). That seems to help. I will correct it.

Comment: Thanks for all advice, I tried to reduce the number of calls in particular where I called ixsym(i,j) with the same arguments inside a loop but that created numerical problems. My code is not well structured and fairly fragile.  I guess I have assumed Fortran would discover if I called a function with the same arguments inside a loop it would call it only once.  For lookup tables my matrices can vary a lot in size, from 1x1 to 200x200 or more but I may try that if there is no other way.  I tried also @kvatours variant but there was no gain in speed, I guess branching is not an issue.

Comment: So you have many different size matrices at once? One lookup table, the one for the largest matrix should be usable for all smaller matrices as well. (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you might consider is to get rid of the branching in that function:

The minimum and maximum of two numbers can be computed as:

```
max = (a+b + abs(a-b))/2
min = (a+b - abs(a-b))/2 = a+b - max
```

So you can use this as

```
integer function ixsym(i,j)
   integer :: p, q
   q = i+j; p = (q + abs(i-j))/2; q = q - p
   ixsym = q + (p*(p-1))/2        
   return
end
```

which you can further reduce as

```
integer function ixsym(i,j)
   integer :: p
   ixsym = i+j; p = (ixsym + abs(i-j))/2;
   ixsym = ixsym + (p*(p-3))/2        
   return
end
```

Comment: I would just call t min and max intrinsic.

Comment: @VladimirF The idea was to get rid of Branching. Those functions most likely have branching.

Comment: @kvantour On x64 it's optimized without branching, using `cmov` instructions. But you still have a multiplication, and I expect this part can usually be set outside of tight loops. There is also a (mostly useless) function call to `ixsym` wherever it's used (which may or may not be optimized away).